# Bypass git server side hooks

Tags: git

When I try to push commits made by other people, git server rejects the commits with pre-receive hook declined:

> expected committer name 'John' but found 'Jill'

Is there a way to bypass this server side hook without asking repo admin to change policy?

I don't want to take credit for commits that other people have made. Also, this is a result of moving files with their histories from one repo to another. I want to preserve said history.

Comment: Well, there're two persons in each git commits, `Author` and `Committer`. A correctly configured server-side hook should check committer, not author. If it's not correct then probably you can't do anything with that on your own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to bypass [a] server side hook without asking repo admin to change policy?

Not generally, no.  The specifics depend on the hook.  For instance, it's easy to write a server-side hook that rejects commits with the word `fnord` in the log message *unless* the word `slack!` (complete with exclamation point) *also* appears somewhere in the log message.  Hence it's possible that your server-side hook will allow a different committer-name if some other item is also set some specific way.

That said, though:

> I don't want to take credit for commits that other people have made.

The *committer* in a commit is, deliberately, not the *author* of the commit.  Every commit in git has two separate users—name, email address, and date—attached.  One is the commit's *author* and the other is the *committer*.  Submitting a commit with you as the committer, and someone else as the author, is the standard way of declaring that the someone-else is the author of that commit, and you merely put it into the repository.

Comment: Indeed, just replacing committer variables with git filter-branch --commit-filter did what I needed. Thanks.